# Скачивание .swf

Tags: javascript

Имеется ссылка вида `<a href="test.swf">Скачать</a>`.

Как реализовать скачивание .swf объекта на локалку при нажатии на нее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте атрибут `download="имя файла при скачивании.swf"`

Answer (score 1):

Добавить файлу http-заголовок

```
content-disposition: attachment
```

или использовать атрибут `download` у ссылки (но он [не везде поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href$=".swf"]').each(function(index, element){
  element.download = element.href.split('/').pop();
});
```

Всем ссылкам на файлы `.swf` присваиваем свойству `download` имя файла.

Comment: вообще говоря, тут не атрибут. а свойство присваивается